# Parse VCF file's INFO field

Tags: bash, awk, sed, bioinformatics, vcf-variant-call-format

Please help me parse a *[VCF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variant_Call_Format)* file. I am pasting a real example.

Input:

```
1   1014143 rs786201005 C   T   .   .   RS=786201005;RSPOS=1014143;dbSNPBuildID=144;SSR=0;SAO=1;VP=0x050068000605000002110100;GENEINFO=ISG15:9636;WGT=1;VC=SNV;PM;PMC;NSN;REF;ASP;LSD;OM;CLNALLE=1;CLNHGVS=NC_000001.11:g.1014143C>T;CLNSRC=OMIM_Allelic_Variant;CLNORIGIN=1;CLNSRCID=147571.0003;CLNSIG=5;CLNDSDB=MedGen:OMIM:Orphanet;CLNDSDBID=C4015293:616126:ORPHA319563;CLNDBN=Immunodeficiency_38_with_basal_ganglia_calcification;CLNREVSTAT=no_criteria;CLNACC=RCV000162196.3
1   1014228 rs1921  G   A,C .   .   RS=1921;RSPOS=1014228;dbSNPBuildID=36;SSR=0;SAO=0;VP=0x050328000a0517053f000100;GENEINFO=ISG15:9636;WGT=1;VC=SNV;PM;PMC;S3D;SLO;NSM;REF;ASP;VLD;G5A;G5;HD;GNO;KGPhase1;KGPhase3;CLNALLE=1;CLNHGVS=NC_000001.11:g.1014228G>A;CLNSRC=.;CLNORIGIN=1;CLNSRCID=.;CLNSIG=2;CLNDSDB=MedGen;CLNDSDBID=CN169374;CLNDBN=not_specified;CLNREVSTAT=single;CLNACC=RCV000455759.1;CAF=0.6611,0.3389,.;COMMON=1
1   1014316 rs672601345 C   CG  .   .   RS=672601345;RSPOS=1014319;dbSNPBuildID=142;SSR=0;SAO=1;VP=0x050068001205000002110200;GENEINFO=ISG15:9636;WGT=1;VC=DIV;PM;PMC;NSF;REF;ASP;LSD;OM;CLNALLE=1;CLNHGVS=NC_000001.11:g.1014319dupG;CLNSRC=OMIM_Allelic_Variant;CLNORIGIN=1;CLNSRCID=147571.0002;CLNSIG=5;CLNDSDB=MedGen:OMIM:Orphanet;CLNDSDBID=C4015293:616126:ORPHA319563;CLNDBN=Immunodeficiency_38_with_basal_ganglia_calcification;CLNREVSTAT=no_criteria;CLNACC=RCV000148989.5
1   1014359 rs672601312 G   T   .   .   RS=672601312;RSPOS=1014359;dbSNPBuildID=142;SSR=0;SAO=1;VP=0x050068000605000002110100;GENEINFO=ISG15:9636;WGT=1;VC=SNV;PM;PMC;NSN;REF;ASP;LSD;OM;CLNALLE=1;CLNHGVS=NC_000001.11:g.1014359G>T;CLNSRC=OMIM_Allelic_Variant;CLNORIGIN=1;CLNSRCID=147571.0001;CLNSIG=5;CLNDSDB=MedGen:OMIM:Orphanet;CLNDSDBID=C4015293:616126:ORPHA319563;CLNDBN=Immunodeficiency_38_with_basal_ganglia_calcification;CLNREVSTAT=no_criteria;CLNACC=RCV000148988.5
1   1020183 rs539283387 G   C   .   .   RS=539283387;RSPOS=1020183;dbSNPBuildID=142;SSR=0;SAO=0;VP=0x050000000a05040026000100;GENEINFO=AGRN:375790;WGT=1;VC=SNV;NSM;REF;ASP;VLD;KGPhase3;CLNALLE=1;CLNHGVS=NC_000001.11:g.1020183G>C;CLNSRC=.;CLNORIGIN=1;CLNSRCID=.;CLNSIG=3;CLNDSDB=MedGen;CLNDSDBID=CN169374;CLNDBN=not_specified;CLNREVSTAT=single;CLNACC=RCV000424799.1;CAF=0.9904,0.009585;COMMON=1
1   1020216 rs764659938 C   G   .   .   RS=764659938;RSPOS=1020216;dbSNPBuildID=144;SSR=0;SAO=0;VP=0x050000000a05040002000100;GENEINFO=AGRN:375790;WGT=1;VC=SNV;NSM;REF;ASP;VLD;CLNALLE=1;CLNHGVS=NC_000001.11:g.1020216C>G;CLNSRC=.;CLNORIGIN=1;CLNSRCID=.;CLNSIG=0;CLNDSDB=MedGen;CLNDSDBID=CN221809;CLNDBN=cancer;CLNREVSTAT=single;CLNACC=RCV000422793.1
```

And I need an output:

```
1014143 rs786201005 C   T   CLNSIG=5    CLNDBN=Immunodeficiency_38_with_basal_ganglia_calcification
1014228 rs1921  G   A,C CLNSIG=2    CLNDBN=not_specified
1014316 rs672601345 C   CG  CLNSIG=5    CLNDBN=Immunodeficiency_38_with_basal_ganglia_calcification
1014359 rs672601312 G   T   CLNSIG=5    CLNDBN=Immunodeficiency_38_with_basal_ganglia_calcification
1020183 rs539283387 G   C   CLNSIG=3    CLNDBN=not_specified
1020216 rs764659938 C   G   CLNSIG=0    CLNDBN=not_provided
```

That means print column *2,3,4,5* and then parse last column and print just *CLNSIG* and *CLNDBN*. Problem is, that those values are not always in the same position.

My try was:

```
awk -v OFS="\t"'{print $2,$3,$4,$5,$8}' input
```

...and then I have no clue how to get *CLNSIG* and *CLNDBN*.

Thank you for any ideas.

Comment: @EdMorton I just wanted to copy all text to better explain input file. Input and ouptu are clear - extract column delimited by tabulator 2,3,4,5,8 and then from last 8th column extract  only CLNSIG+CLNDBN and its values.

Comment: I would advise to do this with a small script in a language such as perl or python. It is then easy to split the last field on the ";" and use the resulting elements to build a "dictionary" (in python vocabulary) that allows you to select what piece of information you are interested in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `perl`

```
$ perl -lane 'print join "\t",(@F[1..4], /(?:CLNSIG|CLNDBN)=[^;]+/g)' ip.txt
1014143 rs786201005 C   T   CLNSIG=5    CLNDBN=Immunodeficiency_38_with_basal_ganglia_calcification
1014228 rs1921  G   A,C CLNSIG=2    CLNDBN=not_specified
1014316 rs672601345 C   CG  CLNSIG=5    CLNDBN=Immunodeficiency_38_with_basal_ganglia_calcification
1014359 rs672601312 G   T   CLNSIG=5    CLNDBN=Immunodeficiency_38_with_basal_ganglia_calcification
1020183 rs539283387 G   C   CLNSIG=3    CLNDBN=not_specified
1020216 rs764659938 C   G   CLNSIG=0    CLNDBN=cancer
```

- `-a` option to split input on white-space, saved in `@F` array
- `/(?:CLNSIG|CLNDBN)=[^;]+/g` will return the `CLNSIG` and `CLNDBN` fields
- `@F[1..4]` gives fields 2nd to 5th (index starts from `0`)
- See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches for details on `-lane` options

Answer (score 3):

1. Pure `bash`, works by using `bash` to parse the remaining variables
   in `$h`, with *[parameter tranformation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)* output:

   ```
   while read a b c d e f g h ; do 
       declare ${h//;/ }
       printf "%s\t%-10s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n" $b $c $d $e ${CLNSIG@A} ${CLNDBN@A}
   done < input
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   1014143 rs786201005 C   T   CLNSIG='5'  CLNDBN='Immunodeficiency_38_with_basal_ganglia_calcification'
   1014228 rs1921      G   A,C CLNSIG='2'  CLNDBN='not_specified'
   1014316 rs672601345 C   CG  CLNSIG='5'  CLNDBN='Immunodeficiency_38_with_basal_ganglia_calcification'
   1014359 rs672601312 G   T   CLNSIG='5'  CLNDBN='Immunodeficiency_38_with_basal_ganglia_calcification'
   1020183 rs539283387 G   C   CLNSIG='3'  CLNDBN='not_specified'
   1020216 rs764659938 C   G   CLNSIG='0'  CLNDBN='cancer'
   ```
2. *POSIX* shell, `grep` and `printf` method:

   ```
   while read a b c d e f g h ; do
       printf "%s\t%-10s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n" $b $c $d $e \
             $( echo "$h" | grep -o 'CLN\(SIG\|DBN\)=[^;]*' ) ; 
   done < input
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   1014143 rs786201005 C   T   CLNSIG=5    CLNDBN=Immunodeficiency_38_with_basal_ganglia_calcification
   1014228 rs1921      G   A,C CLNSIG=2    CLNDBN=not_specified
   1014316 rs672601345 C   CG  CLNSIG=5    CLNDBN=Immunodeficiency_38_with_basal_ganglia_calcification
   1014359 rs672601312 G   T   CLNSIG=5    CLNDBN=Immunodeficiency_38_with_basal_ganglia_calcification
   1020183 rs539283387 G   C   CLNSIG=3    CLNDBN=not_specified
   1020216 rs764659938 C   G   CLNSIG=0    CLNDBN=cancer
   ```

Answer (score 2):

It can be done using awk:

**script.awk**

```
BEGIN { OFS="\t" }
      { clnsig = clndbn = ""
        if( match( $8, /CLNSIG=[^;]+/ ) ) {
          clnsig = substr( $8, RSTART, RLENGTH )
        }
        if( match( $8, /CLNDBN=[^;]+/ ) ) {
          clndbn = substr( $8, RSTART, RLENGTH )
        }
        print $2, $3, $4, $5, clnsig, clndbn
      }
```

Or more compact, in case that `CLNDBN` is **always** after `CLNSIG`:

**script.awk**

```
BEGIN { OFS="\t" }
    { match($8,/(CLNSIG=[^;]+).*(CLNDBN=[^;]+)/, tmp) 
      print $2,$3,$4,$5, tmp[1], tmp[2]
    }
```

The function `match` matches a regular expression. The first form sets the variables `RSTART` and `RLENGTH` so that you can extract the text with `substring`.

The second form puts the first subexpression (first parentheses) in the array `tmp` at pos 1, the second subexpression at pos 2 and so on.

The regular expression `CLNSIG=[^;]+` matches a literal `CLNSIG=` followed by a substring up to (but not including) the `;`.